# Split string in multiple without index

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have people addresses in string, what I want to do is extract city and state names  from these address and store rest of the string as address. problem is I don't have any idea about how long the addresses are.

for example:

```
let address1 = "Akshardham Temple, Vidyut Nagar, Vaishali Nagar, Chitrakoot, Jaipur, Rajasthan"

let address2 = "Statue of Unity, Statue of Unity Road, Kevadia, Gujarat"

// and some might be just this
let address3 = "New Delhi, Delhi"
```

what I want is however long string is I want to extract last two entire words(state and city) and rest in another variable.

Comment: 1. Use `split` to explode the string with comma. 2. With `length` you can know the size of the array. 3. Now you can access the last array element and -1 to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split the string by a comma:

`const arr = address1.split(',');`

This will give you an array of strings, e.g. `["Akshardham Temple", " Vidyut Nagar", " Vaishali Nagar", " Chitrakoot", " Jaipur", " Rajasthan"]`

Then you can slice off the last 2 elements of the array:

`const [city, state] = arr.slice(-2)`

Comment: Note the unwanted spaces that are still present in the array: [" Jaipur", " Rajasthan"]. To avoid bugs later, `trim()` should be called on every array element.

Comment: Also, Pradhumn Vaishnav has written that he wants to get the last two entire words. If you use the comma as a separator, you violate this requirement. Example: `let address1 = "Akshardham Temple, Vidyut Nagar, Vaishali Nagar, Chitrakoot Jaipur Rajasthan"`. Your solution works only if the last two words are safely separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you have to split the strings. If you want only whole words, it makes sense to use the space character as a separator.

```
const parts = address1.split(" ");
```

Now you have to access the last element and the second last element. Remember that `length` is always one greater than the last index.

```
const lastWort = parts[parts.length-1];
const secondLastWort = parts[parts.length-2];
```

If you are bothered by the commas in the result, you can remove them first.

```
address1 = address1.replaceAll(",", "");
```

All together:

```js
let address1 = "Akshardham Temple, Vidyut Nagar, Vaishali Nagar, Chitrakoot, Jaipur, Rajasthan";

address1 = address1.replaceAll(",", "");

const parts = address1.split(" ");

const lastWort = parts[parts.length-1];
const secondLastWort = parts[parts.length-2];

console.log(lastWort);
console.log(secondLastWort);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `splice`. The returned elements would need a call to `trim()` so to avoid optional white space is dangling around the extracted words:

```js
function splitAddress(s) {
    let parts = s.split(",");
    let [city, state] = parts.splice(-2).map(s => s.trim());
    return { address: parts.join(","), city, state };
}

let tests = [
    "Akshardham Temple, Vidyut Nagar, Vaishali Nagar, Chitrakoot, Jaipur, Rajasthan",
    "Statue of Unity, Statue of Unity Road, Kevadia, Gujarat",
    "New Delhi, Delhi"
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(splitAddress(test));
}
```